# Display content of all files (from current directory) whose names contain character "a" or "A" appearing at least 3 times

Tags: regex, bash, shell, directory, find

I have to get the content of all files names matching the pattern (include "a" or "A" appearing at least 3 times, they dont have to be set in a row, there can be spaces or other letters or characters between)
I can't figure why my regex isn't working there. If I run the script, there is no output.

Let's for example look for a file named "Alabama" as we can see it matches the said pattern.

Tried -regex here:

```
find . -type f -regex '([^a]*a){3}' -exec cat {} \;
```

Tried -name too:

```
find . -type f -name '([^a]*a){3}' -exec cat {} \;
```

But none of these work. If I put a normal string in

```
find . -type f -name 'string' -exec cat {} \;
```

It normally works and displays the content of file named 'string'.

Any advices how to make it work and find the correct files matching the pattern? Is the pattern wrong? (I'm just learning the bash so any advices are appreciated)

Comment: `-regex '.*/\([^a]*a\)\{3\}.*'`

Comment: Tried using that regex pattern and it still does not find the file that matches it. Do You think it is correct? @Wiktor 

 find . -type f -regex '.*/\([^a]*a\)\{3\}.*' -exec cat {} \;

Comment: `cat *[aA]*[aA]*[aA]*`?

Comment: Actually cat command is all i needed! This works perfectly, regex too @Shawn
Thank You :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the point of the exercise is to use regular expressions (Or `find`), it can be done with a plain old wildcard pattern:

```
cat *[aA]*[aA]*[aA]*
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the original try didn't work because the default regex engine of `find` [does not support the `{}` operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html).
Changing the engine to grep (must escape parenthesis) and accounting for characters after the last `a`:

`find . -type f -regextype grep -regex '\(.*[aA]\)\{3\}.*'`

Or, since all you care about are the 3 `a`s:

`find . -type f -regex '.*[aA].*[aA].*[aA].*'`